# SELENIUM DRIVER и русский язык

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, phantomjs

Здравствуйте. Вот код:

```
        IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);

        Console.WriteLine("Write search domain:");
        string domain = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Write search word:");
        string word = Console.ReadLine();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=" + word);
        ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("my.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return;
```

При вводе "Привет, мир!"
Отображается (на скрине) следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему?
P.S. Пробывал играться с кодировками, но проблема именно в драйвере, т.к. кодировки вообще никак не меняют результата...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `Uri.EscapeUriString` для преобразования параметра url.

Подробнее на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4550600/4928642).

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло. Кому-то может пригодится: string word = Console.ReadLine();
            string search = Uri.EscapeUriString("https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=" + word);

Comment: @PostMix, странно... По идее, надо только слово преобразовывать...